# Return object from a child process to main application

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

In my main script, I am running as a subsequent script using the `child_process fork`. In my subsequent script, I am doing few operations using an object and then I want to return that object instance to the main application (not a string but a c++ binding object). Can I do this?
If so could you please show me a sample of such object return.

Comment: You could use `send()` method in your child process to send the data back to parent process. and in parent process, you need a listener on `message` to receive the data. More details over here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback

Comment: There is an example in the documentation under `subprocess.send` on how to send messages from forked processes. I don't know if it works for that kind of object.